# Performance tuning in Sybase

Tags: performance, sybase, tuning

Does Sybase have a tool like AWR in Oracle which can be used to identify high load SQL, tell the important waits that are happening, help in understanding the workload? 
What are the main tools to be used to identify high load SQL and tune query performance?

Comment: `optdiag` and monitoring tables are the tools to monitor performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically like AWR, but there are a number of built-in tools that can be deployed.

The "mda" tables will be your best friends for identifying poorly performing queries.

Rob Verschoor's site has detailed information on how to use them along with some pre-built tools.

http://www.sypron.nl/mda.html

Official documentation can be found here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc70002.1570/html/title.htm

sp_sysmon, monserver and historical server may be of little use. They're more suited to server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative like awr in sybase. However by using monTables and sp_sysmon, You can achieve the same result or better than awr.

If you are looking only for a specific issue, It is recommended that you adjust sp_sysmon as per the requirements and saves the result to the file system or in another database. It makes it is easier to interpret data and to find the full extent of the tuning parameters.

sp_sysmon is a powerful tool which not only displays the data, It also gives the recommendations for the parameters to improve the server performance.

If you can tell me the areas where you are looking into, I can update you the monTables which you should refers and how to interpret the data as per your needs.